# Shared Worker with webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, websocket, loader, worker

I work on Vue project which use websocket to communicate and transfer data with server, to prevent too much socket open, I try to use Shared Worker. I google many time but there is no library or information how to webpack load Shared Worker, there is Worker-loader but, not yet Shared Worker loader, tried to fork Worker Loader and change line new Worker -> new SharedWorker but no luck.
Is there any solution for this case?
Thanks very much